# How to join empty usermeta in WordPress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm using WordPress.

I have my `wp_users` table with 5 users.

Inside my `wp_usermeta`, 3 users of 5, have a `meta_key` called `age`.

How can I get all 5 users with their age values (null if user doesn't have one) like this:

```
ID|username|age
1|user1|18 
2|user2|18 
3|user3| 
4|user4|18 
5|user5|
```

**IMPORTANT**: I must use a MySQL query, can't use WP functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `LEFT JOIN` to get all rows from `wp_users` table (left-side table), irrespective of any matching row in the `wp_usermeta` table (right-side table).

`meta_key` field is in the right-side table; if you specify `WHERE` condition on that field, it would effectively become a `INNER JOIN`. You need to specify these conditions in the `ON` clause:

```
select u.ID, u.user_email, m.meta_value 
from wp_users AS u 
left join wp_usermeta AS m 
       on u.ID = m.user_id 
          AND m.meta_key= 'user_updated'
```

Also, in case of multi-table queries, it is a good practice to use [Aliasing](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias), for code disambiguation and readability.

Comment: So stupid! Of course, that's it. Thank you! Just edit your `meta_value` alias from `u` to `m` for future readers

Answer (score 1):

You should not use column from left joined table in where condition  this work as INNER JOIN  . . you should move these condition in left join ON clause

```
select wp_users.ID, wp_users.user_email, wp_usermeta.meta_value 
from wp_users 
left join wp_usermeta on wp_users.ID=wp_usermeta.user_id
      AND wp_usermeta.meta_key= 'user_updated'
```